# Molecules that get charged in Water

Tags: molecules

I am a chemistry super noob and I was watching a MIT video where the professor states that:

"Certain molecules become charged when they come in contact with water in the natural state"

Can someone give me an example of one or more such molecules ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context how he meant it. I could imagine two scenarios:

- Certain materials can produce ions when they dissolved in water. A typical example is table salt, NaCl. Table salt is solid form has a lattice that contains Na+ and Cl+ ions, and when you put it in water, the water molecules can help releasing these ions into the solution, where you now can find the ions. Note, that in this case the ions are atomic entities but molecules with charge are also ions, like $\ce{MnO4-}$ or $\ce{SO}_4^{2-}$.
- Another scenario when the charged entities are formed as a reaction with water by e.g. giving an electron (oxidation) to water molecules or to other dissolved components e.g. oxygen in water. As you can imagine, it happens generally with very reactive materials (materials that are very sensitive to moisture), but essentially the rusting of iron is a similar reaction.

Comment: An addition: amino acids often gain or lose charge in water depending on the pH.

Answer (score 1):

Terrible phrasing. Molecules by definition have no *overall* charge. Ions have overall charge. Not molecules. Molecules becoming charged become ions.

If you want to get into the nitty gritty you can try looking up more information about *zwitterions*, which are actually **not** ions in the strict sense as they possess no *net* charge.

This is the IUPAC definition of **molecule**:

> **An electrically neutral entity** consisting of more than one atom (n > 1). Rigorously, a molecule, in which  n > 1 must correspond to a depression on the potential energy surface that is deep enough to confine at least one vibrational state.

This is the IUPAC definition of **ion**:

> An atomic or molecular particle having a **net electric charge**.

This is the IUPAC definition of **zwitterion**:

> **Neutral compounds** having formal unit electrical charges of opposite
>   sign. Some chemists restrict the term to compounds with the charges on
>   non-adjacent atoms. Sometimes referred to as inner salts, dipolar ions
>   (a misnomer). E.g. H3N+CH2C(=O)O− ammonioacetate (glycine),
>   (CH3)3N+–O− trimethylamine oxide.

http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html

Comment: So, betaine is a molecule and not an ion?

Comment: Yes, it would. It is also a "zwitterion" since it has formal charges of opposite signs on its constituent ions. See here for the IUPAC definition of molecule - it does not contradict anything I said. http://goldbook.iupac.org/M04002.html

Comment: Good point, it is better be careful about this detail. Interesting that the adjective form "molecular" is still used in the other sense, irrespective of charge.

Comment: Well that's an unfortunately loose application of terms.